# Pulling HTML element from PHP string and inserting into another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a PHP string with something like this inside:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- nothing important in here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
            ...
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I then have a HTML page with a div with an id. I would like to somehow extract that table from the PHP string and paste it into my div. I cannot edit the HTML in the PHP string (so I cannot add an ID to the table to pull it out). How would I do this? I have tried using iframes but by browser is blocking them.

Comment: use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($somestring);
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    echo $table->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $table );
}
```

If you want to do stuff with the table, take a look at [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#88441) / [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)